# How to make a simple jQuery filter list accept only whole words, so it doesn't match partial words, only whole words

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, cpu-word, match

http://jsfiddle.net/nicktheandroid/U8T8p/4/

```
(function($) {

    $('.filterinput').keyup(function() {
        var filter = $(this).val();
        if (filter.length > 2) {
            // this finds all links in the list that contain the input,
            // and hide the ones not containing the input while showing the ones that do
            $(list).find("a:not(:Contains(" + filter + "))").parent().slideUp();
            $(list).find("a:Contains(" + filter + ")").parent().slideDown();
        } else {
            $(list).find("li").slideDown();
        }
        return false;
    })

}(jQuery));
```

This will filter the list based on if what you've typed matches ANY part of a word in the list. I'm trying to make it only match whole words, so it wont say it has a match until the full word is typed. Would Regex be best? Or? I need help, nothing I've tried has worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/U8T8p/10/

```
        var containing = $('#list li').filter(function () {
            var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + a, 'i');
            return regex.test($('a', this).text());
        }).slideDown();
        $('#list li').not(containing).slideUp();
```

The regex limits matches to those where the currently entered text starts at a word boundary. So, having typed 'Stat' you'd still match 'United States'. You can make it match a full word by changing to `RegExp('\\b' + a + '\\b', i)`.

Comment: Beautiful, do you know how to make it so it doesn't hide all the list items until it actually finds the word? I tried, but it would only work once you type the entire word, then another character, then delete that extra character, only then would it show a match, if you just type the full word, it will hide all of them: http://jsfiddle.net/nicktheandroid/frstz/1/ would you know how to fix that so it doesn't filter until the user types the full word?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you're asking. Can you give a few examples? e.g. If the user types "XXX" then "YYY", "ZZZ" and "123" should be displayed.

Comment: My script has evolved a little since I initially asked the question: http://jsfiddle.net/QhL2M/19/ first of all: you have to type the full word to get it to filter, which is what I want. But notice that once you start typing, after 2 characters, the entire list hides, **I'm trying to make it so the entire list doesn't hide, I want the entire list to stay visible until the user types a word that matches one or more of the list elements, then the ones that don't match are hidden.** The user can type in multiple words, and all list items that match a word in the input are visible.

Comment: Nothing hides unless there is at least one match. Will match all list items containing at least a word of the input: http://jsfiddle.net/nachito/QhL2M/24/

Comment: wow, you know what you're doing. I spent 10+ hours trying to figure out how to do that. If I could, ask one last thing: when typing a word into the input like "apples"(plural tense), I want it to be able to match the word "apple"(singular tense). At one time it was working correctly, but somewhere along the line it's been reversed, so right now if you type "apple", it will match "apples" in the list, that's backwards. I made exceptions for **'s**, **es**, and **s**, it's this line: `var r = new RegExp('\\b(' + inputWords[i] + ')(s|es|\'s)?\\b', 'i');` Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the `filter` method as already mentioned. Or you can easily extend jQuery with your own custom filter which is great way to reuse code.

```
$.expr[':'].containsWord = function(elem, index, match) {
    var text = $(elem).text();
    return !!text.match(new RegExp('\\b' + match[3] + '\\b'));
};
```

and now use it like you would do with any other built-in filter `:containsWord('Some word')`.
See http://jsfiddle.net/U8T8p/9/

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/U8T8p/5/

```
$(list).find("a").filter(function() { return $(this).text() != filter; }).parent().slideUp();
$(list).find("a").filter(function() { return $(this).text() === filter; }).parent().slideDown();
```

Comment: It works, but it'd be better to test with .match() in the second line and including a .stop() after .parent() in both lines. Good job!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.filter` to check the texts and slide these elements down, and pass these elements as a jQuery object to `.not` to get the other elements to slide up: http://jsfiddle.net/U8T8p/8/.

```
(function($) {

    $('.filterinput').keyup(function() {
        var filter = $(this).val();
        if (filter.length > 2) {
            var a = $(list).find("a");

            var x = a.filter(function() {
                return $(this).text() === filter;
            });

            x.parent().slideDown();

            a.not(x).parent().slideUp();
        } else {
            $(list).find("li").slideDown();
        }
        return false;
    })

}(jQuery));
```